# How can I install cold fusion on CentOS?

Tags: coldfusion

I have to install cold fusion.  I know nothing at all about it. I was, in fact, surprised it was still being used.

Server is Centos5 with whm,

Apache 2.0.x

Can anyone point me in the direction even to get started?  There is no open source version right?

Comment: Btw, product is called ColdFusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adobe provides great installation docs: for [CF8](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/Part_1_Installing_1.html) and for [CF9](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Installing/index.html) (dunno which version you're going to use).

There **are** OSS alternatives, in fact. My personal engine of choise is [Railo](http://www.getrailo.org/) (there's [Apache HOWTO](http://www.getrailo.org/index.cfm/documentation/installation/railo-resin-apache/)), also you may want to look at the [OpenBD](http://www.openbluedragon.org/).

P.S. If this was a joke, it was not funny at all: `I was, in fact, surprised it was still being used.`

Comment: It's a reasonable comment.  I've been surprised before as well.  http://langpop.com/

Comment: If you don't know about something, it doesn't mean it does not exist. CF has large and active community, and for years produces tons of enterprise and OSS projects. We just are not so loud on the interwebs as others.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Appreciated.  As for the surprise, I still feel it's valid.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Open Source version of the Adobe ColdFusion engine, so you'd have to license it. If you have a copy of the server, [this Adobe guide here](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/5.0/Installing_and_Configuring_ColdFusion_Server/lininstall.htm) might help you get it configured (although that's for v5).

A [quick google](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=coldfusion+open+source&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a) indicates that there might be a few Cold Fusion compatible open-source servers around.

Comment: Links for CF5 for newcomers, are you kidding?